# Constructing an odd trigonometric function with no 1st-order term in Taylor expansion

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, trigonometry, taylor-expansion

Is it possible to construct a polynomial $f$ of at least one of (the fewer, the better) $$\sin{x},\cos{x},\sin{y},\cos{y},\sin{z},\cos{z}$$ with the following properties?

1. The smaller degree of $f$, the better. Hopefully a linear or quadratic one.
2. it's odd. $f(x,y,z)=-f(-x,-y,-z)$
3. the Taylor expansion of $f$ around $(0,0,z_0)$ (for some nonzero $z_0$) has a nonzero constant term but no 1st-order term.

For example, $f=a-b\cos{y}=a-b+O(y^2)$ satisfies 1.3. but not 2 while $f=\sin{z}$ satisfies 1.2. but not 3.

Comment: $(\sin x)^3$ is odd, has constant term zero, and no 1st-order term.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Sorry, I mean nonzero constant term.

Comment: Have you ever seen an odd function with a nonzero constant term?

Comment: @GerryMyerson Note that the Taylor expansion is around $z_0$ not the origin.

Comment: Yes, there are (for generic values of $z_0$) quadratic polynomials $f$ (but no linear polynomials) satisfying (2) and (3). Perhaps indicate the attempts you've made so far to solve the problem.

Comment: "any nonzero $z_0$" or "a nonzero $z_0$"?

Comment: @Travis The $\sin$s should be of odd degrees. I tried $\sin()\cos()$ like ones and some other. But unfortunately, I couldn't find a quadratic one. Could you show an answer? Thank you.

Comment: I think that when I posted that comment, it was not stated that $z_0\ne0$. That was only edited in later.

Comment: As easy to understand the required function cannot be continous at $z=0$. Therefore it cannot be constructed as a *finite* polynomial expression.

Comment: @user Could you explain why discontinuous? Travis said there’s such functions. But I did’t find any.

Comment: In fact it is simpler and probably also more correct to consider differentiability instead of continuity. I would assume the comment of Travis concerned the case of a certain (though arbitrary) non-zero $z_0$. Now you claim that the linear term is absent for *any* $z_0\ne0$. But the only differentiable function with such a property is a constant, and an odd constant function is $0$.

Comment: @user I see what you mean now. In that sense, I mean a certain (although arbitrary) nonzero $z_0$. But still I didn’t find one. Do you know any?

Comment: @Travis Hello. Do you mind exemplifying a quadratic one?

Comment: Sure, I've written up a short answer explaining how to find a solution. As I said in my comment, the formula only holds for generic values of $z_0$, specifically when $\sin z_0 \neq 0$. If $\sin z_0 = 0$, on the other hand, then it follows from your observation than the total degrees of the $\sin$ factors in each term must be odd that $f(0, 0, z_0) = 0$, so that the constant term vanishes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Quadratic polynomials meeting the requirement is in general possible.

Inspired by comments from @Travis, I got this answer.

It seems that working on $2\pi$-periodic functions of $z$ would suffice. Thus, for an odd $f(z)$, we can use the Fourier series $$f(z)=\sum_{n=1}a_n\sin{nz}.$$
The requirement is **two**-fold: nonzero constant term and vanishing 1st-order term, which means **two** tuning parameters (i.e., quadratic polynomial in the sense of the question) might be enough. Then one can pick out *any* **two** terms in the series above. Let's just use the first two $$f(z)=a_1\sin{z}+a_2\sin{2z}.$$
Its Taylor expansion around $z_0$ reads $$f(z)=(a_1\sin{z_0}+a_2\sin{2z_0})+(a_1\cos{z_0}+2a_2\cos{2z_0})(z-z_0)+O(z-z_0)^2.$$
To fulfill the two conditions, we need solve $$A\begin{bmatrix}
a_1  
\\a_2
\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
\lambda  
\\0
\end{bmatrix}$$ where $\lambda$ is any arbitrary constant (can be independent of $z_0$) we'd like to assign as the nonzero constant term and $$A=\begin{bmatrix}
\sin{z_0} & \sin{2z_0} \\
\cos{z_0} & 2\cos{2z_0} 
\end{bmatrix}.$$
Noting that $\mathrm{Det}{A}=-2\sin^3{z_0}$, it can be solved as long as $\sin{z_0}\ne0$
$$a_1=-\lambda  \cos (2 z_0) \csc ^3(z_0),a_2=\frac{1}{2} \lambda  \cot (z_0) \csc ^2(z_0).$$
Therefore, we finally reach a function $$f(z)=a_1\sin{z}+2a_2\sin{z}\cos{z}=\lambda+O(z-z_0)^2.$$

Answer (score 1):

In order for $f$ to be odd, each term must have odd total degree of the factors $\sin x, \sin y, \sin z$. Thus, any linear polynomial $f$ is a linear combination $a \sin x + b \sin y + c \sin z$, and this has Taylor expansion $$f \sim c \sin z_0 + a x + b y + (c \cos z_0) (z - z_0) + \textrm{(higher-order terms)}.$$ This series has nonzero constant term and zero linear term iff $a = b = \cos z_0 = 0, c \neq 0$. So, if $\cos z_0 \neq 0$, any minimal example is at least quadratic.

To produce a quadratic example, it's enough to consider functions of $z$, and by our first observation above, any such odd function is a linear combination $$f := A \sin z + B \sin z \cos z .$$

> The series about $z = z_0$ is $$f \sim (A + B \cos z_0) \sin z_0 + [A \cos z_0 + B (\cos^2 z_0 - \sin^2 z_0)] (z - z_0) + O((z - z_0)^2) ,$$ so for $\sin z_0 \neq 0$ any solution of this form is a multiple of the one determined by $$A = \sin^2 z_0 - \cos^2 z_0, \qquad B = \cos z_0 .$$ On the other hand, if $\sin z_0 = 0$, the first observation in the answer shows that the Taylor series of $f$ has zero constant term, so in this case there is no function $f$ meeting the criteria.

Comment: Thank you for your helpful comments and answers. I also wrote down my own approach. I'm just curious why you deleted your answer soon after posting it.

Answer (score 1):

The following polynomial of $\sin x$ functions only satisfies all the requirements:
$$
f(x,y,z)=\sin z(3\sin^2 z_0 -\sin^2z),
$$
for any $z_0\ne \pi n$.

A similar function using both $\sin x$ and $\cos x $ can be constructed similarly as:
$$
f(x,y,z)=\sin z (\cos 2z_0 - \cos z_0 \cos z).
$$

Comment: @OscarLanzi Quadratic is possible. Check my answer.

Comment: Didn't see that the Taylor expansion has a nonzero center.  Deleting comment.